# failed to resolve com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1

Tags: android, gradle

I add this library to my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.5'
```

but every time I  compile PhotoView library, I get this error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
```

I downloaded the new "Android Support Library 23.2.1 from android SDK manager
but I still get the error. this is really annoying I need help.
my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.5'
```

}

Answer (score 3):

same issue here - solved by updating "Local Maven repository for Support Libraries" to rev. 28 (i updated via Standalone SDK Manager) 
and as mentioned before, every com.android.support:xxx dependency should have the same version.